# How to make a relation in an entity to the latest entity of another entity type by annotation in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity types, `Server` and `ServerStatus`.

`Server` has `@OneToMany` relation to `ServerStatus`.

The two entities are follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Server {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String hostname;
    private String ipAddress;

    // Is it possible to make a relation by annotation?
    //private ServerStatus latestStatus;

}

@Entity
@Data
public class ServerStatus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Server server;

    private boolean alive;

    private Date collectedTime;

    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate() {
        setCollectedTime(new Date());
    }

}
```

Is it possible to make `latestStatus` have the latest entity of `ServerStatus`?

This is a sample project for this question:

https://github.com/izeye/samples-spring-boot-branches/tree/jpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.
Do you want the latestStatus updaated automatically to the 'latest' data or do you want to manage it yourself.

If you want to do it automatically then no, cause the latest data is a result of search for the highest date. But you could add the extra method to your DAO to fetch the correct one for you and set it there.

But if you are happy to keep the track yourself, then
simply add

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="LATEST_ID")
ServerStatus latestStatus;
```

And DONT add mappedby.
But you are in charge of that latest data. Whenever you add new serverstatus, you have to set the new value on the server. It is not going to be picked up by date.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer meets my needs although I hoped doing it automatically at first glance. I guess it's unavailable or even impossible.